# Fill numpy array by rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How can I fill the numpy array by rows?

For example `arr=np.zeros([3,2]).`
I want replace every row by `list = [1,2].`

So output is:

```
[1 2 
 1 2
 1 2]
```

I can make it by hand

```
for x in arr[:]:
    arr[:]=[1,2]
```

But I believe there is more faster ways.

Sorry, please look edit:
Suppose, we have:

```
arr=array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

I want arr[1] array fill by [1,2] like this:

```
arr=array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Comment: Is your original array actually all zeroes?

Comment: Whst is your array's shapw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop isn't necessary.

Making use of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), you can do this with a single assignment:

```
arr[:] = [1,2]
```

Numpy broadcasts the right-hand-side array to a shape assignable to the left-hand-side.

---

As for the second question (in your update), you can do:

```
arr.T[..., 1] = [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, simple assignment to the whole array works:

```
In [952]: arr=np.zeros((3,2),int)
In [953]: arr[...]=[1,2]
In [954]: arr
Out[954]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

That's because the list translates into a (2,) array, which can be broadcasted to (1,2) and then (3,2), to match `arr`:

```
In [955]: arr[...]=np.array([3,2])[None,:]
In [956]: arr
Out[956]: 
array([[3, 2],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 2]])
```

If I want to set values by column, I have to do a bit more work

```
In [957]: arr[...]=np.array([1,2,3])[:,None]
In [958]: arr
Out[958]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

I have to explicitly make a (3,1) array, which broadcasts to (3,2).

=================

I already answered your modified question:

```
In [963]: arr[1,...]=np.array([1,2])[:,None]
In [964]: arr
Out[964]: 
array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

=================

Add `tile` to your toolkit:

```
In [967]: np.tile([1,2],(3,1))
Out[967]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
In [968]: np.tile([[1],[2]],(1,3))
Out[968]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```